# Storing messages in new conversation collections; MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, socket.io, chat

I'm a student working on a chat application for my internship, where I use `socket.io`.

Right now I am busy thinking of a good way to store the messages send in conversations.

As of now I do the following:

- For each conversation between one user and another user, a new collection is made.
- On every message sent, the message is stored in the according conversation collection in a single document.

The collections:

[image: MongoDb collections]

Where the document looks as follows:

[image: document looks like this]

Now I wonder if there is a good argument to be made to have just one collection "conversations", and store all the messages in multiple documents, where each conversation is a new document.

Answer (score 1):

Creating a new collection for every message is very bad idea instead of that you use a simple schema as given below to store your messages

```
const conversation_schema = new Schema({
  from: {
    type: ObjectID,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  to: {
    type: ObjectID,
    ref: 'User'
  },
  messageBody: {  // body of the message(text body/ image blob/ video blob)
    type: String,
  },
  messageType: { // type of the message(text, mp3, mp4, etc...)
    type: String,
  },
  read: { // to boolean flag to mark whether the to user has read the message 
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  createdAt: { // when was this message goit created
    type: Date,
    default: new Date(),
  },
});
```

you can fetch the conversation between the two users using the following query

```
conversations.find({
      $or: [
       {from: 'user1', TO: 'user2},
       {from: 'user2', TO: 'user1},
      ],
    }).populate({ path: 'to', model: User })
      .populate({ path: 'from', model: User })
      .sort({ createdAt: -1 })
```